# .htaccess - Rule being ignored

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I use this line in my .htaccess file to automatically add a trailing slash if not present

```
rewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ /$1/ [NC,R=301]
```

This works fine, until I use these lines to redirect all requests to not files or dirs to index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php
```

This now forwards the page, but doesn't add the trailing slash.

Does anyone know why this wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I added the L for last rule to the first rewriteRule.

So it now looks like this

```
rewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ /$1/ [NC,R=301,L]
```